# Eliminar ultimo texto ingresado do while

Tags: javascript

tengo creado un **do while**, que pedirá textos por **prompt** y finalizara, cuando escriba **ESC** .

A través de una `función invierto dicho texto`, mi pregunta seria como poder eliminar el ultimo texto ingresado, porqu al escribir la palabra **"ESC"**, también me lo esta muestra.

**Resultado:**
Palabras Invertidas
Texto Invertido:

sirhc omall em ,aloH

Texto Invertido: atram omall em ,aloH

*Texto Invertido: cse*

```
document.write("<h1>Palabras Invertidas</h1>");
 var textoInvertido = "";
 do {
 var frase = prompt("Ingresa una frase");
 var textoInvertido = giraPalabras(frase);


document.write("<strong>Texto Invertido:</strong> " +  textoInvertido + "<br />");


} while (frase !== "ESC" && frase !== "esc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Manteniendo el `do-while` solo podrias repetir la condicion de repeticion del ciclo  y la evaluas con el operador logico `&&` ( comentado en el codigo ) , saque la funcion del codigo y puse la frase en minuscula con el metodo `toLowerCase()` para que se entienda el ejemplo

```js
document.write("<h1>Palabras Invertidas</h1>");
 var textoInvertido = "";
 do {
 var frase = prompt("Ingresa una frase").toLowerCase() ;
 var textoInvertido = frase ;
 //devuelve la segunda parte siempre que la primera no se cumpla

(frase !== "esc" ) && document.write("<strong>Texto Invertido:</strong> " +  textoInvertido + "<br />");


} while (  frase !== "esc");
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar una validacion por medio de un if antes de imprimir la linea

```js
9 document.write("<h1>Palabras Invertidas</h1>");
  8  var textoInvertido = "";
  7  do {
  6  var frase = prompt("Ingresa una frase");
  5  var textoInvertido = giraPalabras(frase);
  4 
  3 if (frase !== "ESC" && frase !== "esc"){
  2 document.write("<strong>Texto Invertido:</strong> " +  textoInvertido + "<br
  1 }
10  
  1 
  2 } while (frase !== "ESC" && frase !== "esc");
```

Comment: Gracias, no se me ocurrió, aun queda mucho camino.